# How to unify different fields of different devices into one time series in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Can Apache IoTDB unify different fields of different devices into one time series? The data of our forecasting model comes from data of the measurement point of different devices, and the writing frequency of the devices is different. It is necessary for us to collect these data and put them all together for predictive calculation. Suppose Device 1 has Field A and B, Device 2 has Field C and D, I want to merge these two sets of fields into one time series in 4 colunms, and fill in the previous value if the timestamp is different. Wonder if IoTDB can achieve this and how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean to union the time series horizontally (which means to join different columns of data from multiple devices according to time order) , it is possible to join in Apache IoTDB.

Try `select A, B, C, D from device1, device2 fill(previous)` to both join these data and to fill in the previous value.